# Waiting for another flutter command to release the startup lock

Tags: flutter, command, lockfile

When I run my flutter application it show

> Waiting for another flutter command to release the startup lock

this messages and not proceed further.

Comment: In My case , i open two  diff project and I run the two commands on both 1) flutter build apk 2) flutter run. it stopped executing the other project and waited for the finishing of first project, as first projected finished its execution , second project started execution.

Comment: Below answers not needed. Just setup your sdk path in android studio. Close project, open project. Select pubspec.yaml run (Pub upgrade, Pub get, flutter doctor).

Answer (score 868, accepted):

In my case, the following command in Terminal helped (as suggested by [Günter Zöchbauer's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51679269/waiting-for-another-flutter-command-to-release-the-startup-lock/60781866#comment90322349_51679269)):

```
killall -9 dart
```

On Windows, run the following in a Command Prompt or PowerShell window (as suggested by [upupming's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51679269/waiting-for-another-flutter-command-to-release-the-startup-lock/60781866#comment100196907_53573543)):

```
taskkill /F /IM dart.exe
```

(You can read about taskkill flags in Windows [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/taskkill))

Comment: then,how to proceed,im new to flutter, i just cloned the flutter git and set the env var?

Comment: I would suggest `-9` as a last resort; attempting without it first would be preferred.

Answer (score 95):

Remove this file:

```
<YOUR FLUTTER FOLDER>/bin/cache/lockfile
```

This releases the occupied lock and makes you able to run other commands.

Comment: But the lockfile is locked. It is in use and I can't seem to delete it. OK, it works, but you need to close Android Studio and wait about a minute as well....then you can delete that file.

Comment: This  answer is good if actually no application is using flutter i.e android studio, vscode, cmd, ... etc

Comment: it doesn't work. I delete it and run the command again same problem shows up. I am using ubuntu, never had this much issue in windows

Answer (score 30):

You can try to kill all `flutter` processes.

TL;DR - go to point `4)`

## 1) List of the processes:

```
ps aux
```

## 2) Search name containing with `flutter`:

```
ps aux | grep flutter
```

where output can be like there:

```
stackoverflow     16697   1.5  0.0  4288316    704   ??  S    10:02PM   0:15.80 bash /flutter_path/flutter/bin/flutter --no-color build apk
stackoverflow      2800   1.5  0.0  4288316    704   ??  S     9:59PM   0:18.49 bash /flutter_path/flutter/bin/flutter --no-color pub get
stackoverflow      1215   1.5  0.0  4280124    700   ??  S     9:58PM   0:18.89 bash /flutter_path/flutter/bin/flutter --no-color config --machine
stackoverflow      8449   1.5  0.0  4296508    716   ??  S    10:00PM   0:17.20 bash /flutter_path/flutter/bin/flutter --no-color pub get
stackoverflow      1326   1.4  0.0  4288316    708   ??  S     9:58PM   0:18.97 bash /flutter_path/flutter/bin/flutter daemon
stackoverflow     16687   0.0  0.0  4279100    820   ??  S    10:02PM   0:00.01 bash /flutter_path/flutter/bin/flutter --no-color build apk
stackoverflow      8431   0.0  0.0  4288316    804   ??  S    10:00PM   0:00.02 bash /flutter_path/flutter/bin/flutter --no-color pub get
stackoverflow      2784   0.0  0.0  4288316    704   ??  S     9:59PM   0:00.01 bash /flutter_path/flutter/bin/flutter --no-color pub get
stackoverflow      1305   0.0  0.0  4280124    712   ??  S     9:58PM   0:00.01 bash /flutter_path/flutter/bin/flutter daemon
stackoverflow      1205   0.0  0.0  4279100    788   ??  S     9:58PM   0:00.01 bash /flutter_path/flutter/bin/flutter --no-color config --machine
stackoverflow     11416   0.0  0.0  4268176    536 s000  R+   10:18PM   0:00.00 grep --color flutter
```

## 3) Get processes ID

We need content from **second** column (from above output):

```
ps aux | grep flutter | awk '{print $2}'
```

## 4 a) Kill "automatically":

To list, search and kill all of them you can use

```
kill $(ps aux | grep flutter | grep -v grep  | awk '{print $2}')
```

(you can run it also with `sudo`)

or

```
ps aux | grep flutter | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -15
```

## 4 b) Kill manually

You can kill processes one-by-one using:

```
sudo kill -15 <process_ID>
```

e.g. to kill process with id `13245` use:

```
sudo kill -15 13245
```

If `-15` will not work, you can try `-2` or `-1`.

Final option it is `-9` which should not be used because it prevents the process from doing any cleanup work.

Answer (score 24):

I use a Mac with Visual Studio Code and this is what worked:

**Shutdown** your PC and switch it on again. Don't use the restart function. I restarted 2 times and it didn't work. Only shutdown worked.

PS: I tried out the following:

1. Delete lockfile;
2. Run `killall -9 dart`;
3. Restart my PC.

But they all didn't work.

Answer (score 23):

In Windows :

Press: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd>

- In task manager find out your editor such as VS Studio or Android Studio
- In that Find "dart" and End that Task
- Then close your editor
- Open editor again
- let editor to complete all things, after that run your query that will work

Comment: For me there's no dart task.

Answer (score 15):

Most are saying `killall -9 dart` but nobody mentioned `pkill -f dart` which worked for me.

The difference between the 2 is explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252349/what-is-the-difference-between-kill-pkill-and-killall).

Comment: `pkill -f dart` worked for me on MacOs Ventura.

Answer (score 9):

Exit from your IDE, then from start manager stop all dart related files(if any have).
Then go to
`"FLUTTER DIRECTORY"/bin/cache/lockfile`
and delete this lockfile

Answer (score 7):

I have the same issue, I tried all the above solutions, but none of them worked for me. Then I searched the keywords in flutter directory, and found the following code. So I tried to delete `bin/cache/.upgrade_lock`, and it worked finally.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This also happens when you have opened the flutter project in the Editor. Close the Editor and re-run the command

Comment: To add up to this, I am using vs code and I have to close all instances of vs code (e.g. api & flutter projects). Then I am able to re-run `flutter run`.

Comment: NOT WORKED DEAR :)

Answer (score 5):

I have tried all of below steps, but none worked.

1. Delete lockfile;
2. Run `killall -9 dart;`
3. Restart my PC.

Below is the final command that worked for me

```
rm -rf <flutter_dir>bin/cache/.upgrade_lock
```

Answer (score 4):

I tried all previous suggestions but without benefit.
Finally when I connect my pc to internet and wait flutter to release then 5 minutes solved

Answer (score 4):

In VS code run

```
flutter clean
```

in the terminal. This fixed my issue.

[image: code image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Delete **pubspec.lock** file
2. Run "**flutter pub get**" from terminal **or** editor shortcut ("*get packages*" **AndroidStudio** or [this logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6j4Bw.png) **Visual Studio**) in pubspec.yaml file.
3. Wait for download.
4. If it doesn't work relaunch your editor then repeat **step 2.**.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the issue's root cause on my Mac device was a version of the flock binary it was not expecting. Removing it from the path did the trick; probably a BSD vs GNU syntax issue.

Comment: I had the same cause. `brew upgrade flock` - helped me

Answer (score 2):

I tried all the previous suggestions but no one solved the problem..
I did the following and it works (Windows 11):

1. run command: **taskkill /F /IM dart.exe** in TERMINAL in VS code.
2. close VS code.
3. delete **lockfile** in <flutter_SDK_bath>\bin\cache.
4. restart computer.
5. run command: **flutter doctor** in Power Shell. (especially after updating flutter SDk).
6. run command **flutter pub get** in application path.

that's works for me..

Answer (score 1):

Restart your computer or simple logout from the current user and login again.

Comment: Please convince me logging out&in solves the problem. (And, if platform dependent or tried on one, only, mention the platform.)

Comment: using Mac OS Mojave

Comment: I faced similar issues and the above method solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

1. Turn off Android Studio.
2. Open flutter installation directory /bin/cache.
3. Delete lockfile.
4. At this point, you can execute the flutter related command on the command line to solve the problem perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove flutter and "install again", so fastest way is to:

## 1) Check where you have `flutter` (as executable)

To check it, you can run:

```
which flutter
```

And you can expect such output:

```
/your_user/your_path/flutter/bin/flutter
```

## 2) Go to this directory

Above path is directly to flutter, but we would like to go to directory so "one earlier" in path:

```
cd /your_user/your_path/flutter/bin
```

## 3) Check is it `git` repository

**It should be**, but it's worth to check.

Run one of the git command e.g.

```
git status
```

or

```
git branch
```

When it's git repository you will receive some info about it or correct list of branches.

## 4) Remove all of the files

```
rm -R *
```

## 5) "revert" removal to have only necessary files:

```
git co -- .
```

## 6) Voila!

You can run just `flutter version` and commands should work (and Flutter will fetch some necessary data).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows, you can open the task manager and under the 'Processes' tab search for processes named 'dart'. End all those tasks.

Answer (score 0):

**In Android Studio, It's Work for me**

*Stop your app if it still runs on the phone
or disconnect the your testing device.*

Then try to install the package again.

Answer (score 0):

There are some action to do:

1- in pubspec.yaml press "packages get" or in terminal type " flutter packages get" and wait seconds.

if this doesn't work :

2-type flutter clean then do step(1)

if this doesn't work too :

3-type killtask /f /im dart.exe

if this doesn't work too :

4- close android studio and then restart your pc.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing of ALL these answers didn't helped me.

The only one solution was to remove whole flutter stuff (and reinstall flutter from git):

```
<flutter directory>
<user>/.flutter_tool_state
<user>/.dart
<user>/.pub-cache
<user>/.dartServer
<user>/.flutter
```

Answer (score 0):

i had same issue , in terminal executed this command

taskkill /F /IM dart.exe

and Flutter Clean ,
Flutter pub get
then restarted the pc and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

- In the terminal type `flutter packages get`
- Type `flutter clean`

If it doesn't work do this:

- Type killtask /f /im dart.exe.

Close Android Studio and then restart your PC.

Answer (score 0):

I tried most of the answers here, but what I believe is happening is that there is some hidden dart process running when you open any app like VSCode or Android Studio. My steps were a lot simpler to solve this:

- Shut off your computer (don't just restart it) and turn it back on
- **Don't** open VSCode or Android Studio
- If there's any dart process running, kill it with task manager or with the commands provided by the folks here
- Go to {FlutterDirectory}/bin/cache and delete **everything** there (it's just cache so doesn't matter)
- Open terminal
- Run flutter clean

I believe the flutter/dart extension for VSCode might lock it if you try to run flutter clean in VSCode, but you can try it