# Flutter: Waiting for another flutter commando to release the startup lock

Tags: android, dart, flutter

The following steps were attempted:

- Delete the folder `./build` with the command: `flutter clean`
- Delete duplicate `.dart` processes but it does not work
- Delete the `.lockfile` file, but when I delete it, it generates it again

My operating system is: **Windows 10 Professional 64 bits**

I am using: **Android Studios**

Here is the link to the publication that I read before asking this question:
Url: [Waiting for another flutter command to release the startup lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51679269/waiting-for-another-flutter-command-to-release-the-startup-lock)

[image]


In the list of processes I see 2 or 3 .dart read that closing the .dart process made the construction of the project work. But it is not working.


[image]


I would appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: tried to run `flutter` command from the terminal window? does it print out anything?

Comment: Do you mean to build the application from the windows terminal?

Comment: Yes, I do that all the time

Comment: I closed all .dart processes and also Android Studios.

Then I opened the Windows terminal, I accessed the project and wrote the Flutter build apk but it keeps saying the same thing.

"Waiting for another flutter commando to release the startup lock".

https://i.gyazo.com/aff301164787df834e715fdb7ebce294.png

Comment: does it happen if you delete that lock file too?

Comment: Yes, when you delete and run the command: Flutter build apk rebuilds it again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188679/discussion-between-domingomg-and-pskink).

Answer (score 8):

if your OS is Windows, try this:

```
taskkill /F /IM dart.exe
```

if your OS is OSX, try this:

```
killall -9 dart
```

Answer (score 5):

Try using the following command in terminal window:

```
killall -9 dart
```

Answer (score 3):

`killall -9 dart` did no luck for me.

I had to delete `flutter/bin/cache/lockfile` but after deleting a restart was mandatory for solving my problem

How to delete the lock file

```
cd flutter/bin/cache
rm -rf lockfile
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by deleting `flutter/bin/cache/lockfile` it worked for me in a similar case .You can find full explanation of this issue is in this closed github [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17422) .

Comment: I deleted it from the folder that you indicated but it generates it again.
https://i.gyazo.com/2f3edb3032ce6383aa3b7eeba2cbe2df.gif?_ga=2.14777397.2089147605.1550578772-1008970440.1550578772

Answer (score 0):

I edited my all griddle files and run my app and it worked for me. Here edit means just delete a character and write it again. I don't know why it worked but it actually worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

```
flutter packages pub build_runner watch
```

macos 
terminal

```
which fluter
```

```
rm -rf  /usr/local/bin/flutter/bin/cache/lockfile
```