# Connection terminated during handshake flutter

Tags: windows, macos, flutter, dart, macos-catalina

It's really frustrating, wasted 3 days to get rid of but still on stuck problem showing on macos catalina version 10.15.1 and windows 7 also. My two PC's showing same error. First when i tried to 'get packages'

it's showing this '/Users/mamun/Developer/flutter/bin/flutter --no-color packages get
**Waiting for another flutter command to release the startup lock...**'

after few moments it's showing..

'/Users/mamun/Developer/flutter/bin/flutter --no-color packages get
Running "flutter pub get" in flutterx...
Connection terminated during handshake

pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 1 in 1 second...

Connection terminated during handshake

pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 2 in 2 seconds...,

tried this [Waiting for another flutter command to release the startup lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51679269/waiting-for-another-flutter-command-to-release-the-startup-lock)

& https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/1729 also.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is a country-specific problem. In some countries, you got this error like *Bangladesh* and some *African* countries. I got a solution to this problem, that is use **VPN software** when you want to  ***get Packages***. VPN software uses other country's IP addresses where this google service works perfectly, So you can easily download packages.

Answer (score 1):

Turn on and Off your emulator connection, it will fix it,

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue, my Local Isp blocked pub.dartlang.org that's why it happens.

Comment: what you have done to unblock from your iSP?

Comment: I just told them to unblock, on the other hand i used vpn also

Answer (score 0):

Use vpn.
If you are not using not prepackaged packages:
stop the process with "ctrl + c"
and try it on project location:

> flutter pub get --offline

Answer (score 0):

Use VPN. Or download package from github.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  carousel_pro:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/jlouage/flutter-carousel-pro.git
      ref: master
```

detailed answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54023220/12279445):

Answer (score 0):

this error might not be from your flutter app. Test the url or endpoint on postman.  The server may not be reachable.
you can test with curl, paste this on your terminal.

```
curl -v http://localhost:8082/spring-rest/foos/9
```

replace the url with the url request that fails.

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution related to Routeur forward rules

In my case I had created a different port to use for release mode, but forgot to make a forward rule for the routeur. (thankfully quickly realized my oversight).

Go to your routeur by typing the address 192.168.1.1 in your local browser then enter your routeur password.

Once done go to Advanced -> Security & Firewall -> Port Forwarding -> Add new rule:

```
Protocol: TCP
Schedule: Always
Original port: the port you are using, like 3000
Forward port: same port as above
Forward address: local address of your server: 192.168.1.x
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I came to **China** and I face this problem a lot. Here I must use **VPN** at all. I tried various methods.
The thing I realized is that the issue is mainly found when I use a ***broadband*** connection. I can recover it when I use a ***hotspot*** internet(with vpn/without vpn).

Answer (score -1):

I was using Hotspot VPN when I faced this issue. Disabling the hotspot worked for me. You can check by disabling any HotSpot or VPN.

Answer (score -2):

**Download** the stable version instead of the clone via git:

```
C:\src>git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git -b stable)
```