# Flutter Connection terminated during handshake

Tags: flutter

I have been developing Flutter application with Android studio. but all of a sudden I am stuck with a strange issue which i cant solve . I cant run the application in anyway. it just shows:

```
Running "flutter pub get" in my_payment...                      
   Connection terminated during handshake

   pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 1 in 1 second...

   Connection terminated during handshake

   pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 2 in 2 seconds...
```

I tried to restart my android studio/pc and the router as well but with no luck.
My flutter doctor reports are all ok
can anybody please help me to sort it out?

Comment: I am facing the same issue, network issue may be!

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60919513/flutter-pub-get-cant-get-dependency-plugins-on-windows/60923417#60923417

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connection terminated during handshake flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59561655/connection-terminated-during-handshake-flutter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your company/ISP/country blocking pub.dev
**Use VPN**
VPN - lets you to visit pub.dev with other coutry's IP.