# Running "flutter pub get" in myapp... (This is taking an unexpectedly long time.)

Tags: macos, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

Steps to Reproduce
Download the flutter 1.17.5-stable, unzip to ~/development/tools
install XCode, Android Studio

```
flutter create myapp
```

[This](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/52796) issue is very similar, but was closed with hesitation without knowing the cause of problem. And also [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/62138).

```
flutter pub get --verbose
```

And:

```
flutter doctor -v
```

[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.5, on Mac OS X 10.15.6 19G73, locale en-US)
• Flutter version 1.17.5 at /Users/akbarpulatov/Development/tools/flutter
• Framework revision 8af6b2f038 (3 weeks ago), 2020-06-30 12:53:55 -0700
• Engine revision ee76268252
• Dart version 2.8.4

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.1)
• Android SDK at /Users/akbarpulatov/Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.1
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android
Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.6)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Xcode 11.6, Build version 11E708
• CocoaPods version 1.9.3

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin version 47.1.2
• Dart plugin version 193.7361
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.47.2)
• VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
• Flutter extension version 3.12.2

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
• iPhone SE (2nd generation) • 425DB4B1-5727-4CEA-98EA-95C24EE81C30 • ios •
com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-6 (simulator)

• No issues found!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems the problem is related to ISPs, you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59561655/connection-terminated-during-handshake-flutter) and [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/62138).

you can walkaround the problem, see:

[Connection terminated during handshake flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59561655/connection-terminated-during-handshake-flutter/63831655#63831655)

Answer (score 1):

Once you downloaded Flutter sdk ,Please add your flutter tool to your path
[Check here to update your path](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#update-your-path). Then you can run "**flutter doctor**" from Terminal to check everything fine,still if you face any problem,post here i will help you

Comment: I added it, you can check the question.