# failed HandshakeException: Connection terminated during handshake error in http package when I using firebase function

Tags: flutter, http, google-cloud-functions

I'm using `http` package to get the firebase cloud function data, I'm getting error  in the console as

```
failed HandshakeException: Connection terminated during handshake
```

I added internet permission in the manifest file, what went wrong here

```
static Future<List<List<MajorCentralBankRules>>> getMajorCentralRules() async 
  {

      try{
          final response=await http.get(majorcentralbankurl);
          if(response.statusCode==200)
          {
          final List<List<MajorCentralBankRules>> majorCentralBankRules = majorCentralBankRulesFromJson(response.body);

              print("successful");

              return majorCentralBankRules;
          }
          else
          {
            majorCentralErrorCode=response.statusCode.toString();
            print(response.statusCode);
            print('failed');
          }
      }catch(e)
      {
        print('failed $e');
        majorCentralErrorCode=e.toString();

      }
  }
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Not yet, i solved with some front end logics

Comment: Have you taken a look at [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59561655/connection-terminated-during-handshake-flutter) It's looks like this is a country-specific problem.

Comment: @LouisC I looked but that was an issue here ‍♂️

Comment: @Prasath, could you kindly share your answer (even if its pseudo logic) so that others may solve the problem if they run into this?