# What is HTTP Host Availability in flutter doctor?

Tags: flutter, dart, http

how to fix HTTP Host Availability in flutter doctor :

```
[!] HTTP Host Availability
    X HTTP host "https://cocoapods.org/" is not reachable. Reason: An error occurred while checking the HTTP host:
      Connection terminated during handshake
    X HTTP host "https://maven.google.com/" is not reachable. Reason: An error occurred while checking the HTTP host:
      Connection terminated during handshake
    X HTTP host "https://pub.dev/" is not reachable. Reason: An error occurred while checking the HTTP host: Connection
      terminated during handshake
    X HTTP host "https://cloud.google.com/" is not reachable. Reason: An error occurred while checking the HTTP host:
      Connection terminated during handshake

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

sorry, i don't know that

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61312927) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61073515) solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It basically is a checks for connectivity to the resources you need for Flutter Development. You need to check your connection if it is an issue during running flutter doctor.

By doing a little bit of digging we can also find the actual file in flutter code for http host validation: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/eb1a851f5843efb6cecab020467a2ffea48fd1d3/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/http_host_validator.dart

Answer (score 0):

check your internet connection, I faced this issue too and gone after I tried with better connection.

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[ΓêÜ] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.8, on Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600],
    locale en-US)
[ΓêÜ] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.
0)
[ΓêÜ] Chrome - develop for the web
[ΓêÜ] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.4.3)
[ΓêÜ] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[ΓêÜ] VS Code (version 1.74.1)
[ΓêÜ] Connected device (3 available)
[ΓêÜ] HTTP Host Availability

* No issues found!
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Run this command in terminal:

```
flutter pub cache repair
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on how the proposed solution solves the problem and how it helps the OP.